# react-final-form doest not allow nested forms

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-final-form

I'm trying to create form inside form, main form have list of inputs and at the top of the inputs  where i have to make a modal to pop up and ask to enter name and age, however i'm getting error saying 'form cannot appear as a descendant of form', however i'm following as shown in this example [React Final Form - Nested Forms Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/p7p6lx24xq?file=/index.js) but i'm trying to write it with functional component